# How to convert PDF file into PPT file using java?

Tags: java, libraries

I want to convert a **pdf** file to a **ppt** file in java.

Is there any third party library for this and how can i use it?

Comment: If you want to do it manually without using a Java API you can go to: http://www.convertpdftopowerpoint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Open-Office API](http://api.openoffice.org).

I am personally not too fond of the API due to;

- The bad compatabilty between OpenOffice Writer and Word.
- The complexity of the API.

But it is possible using the API.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how that API can be used to convert an existing PDF file to PowerPoint? Does the API actually support that conversion, or does it merely allow creating a new presentation?

Comment: I have not worked with the Open-Office API in a long time. Depending on your budget constraints, I found the Aspose libraries and API's easy to use and powerful. If you are looking for a great OpenSource version, have a look at https://poi.apache.org/. You will most likely need another library to extract the PDF content and then place in a PPT using (Apache POI)